# Ionic 3 $http.post return empty

Tags: javascript, post, ionic-framework, ionic3

I send a post with Ionic to php server. The server response a text plain but when a try get it, the object is empty.

```
var response = $http.post('https://somthing.com', $rootScope.data);
console.log(response);
return response;
```

Request headers:

```
Host: something.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:8101/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 137
Origin: http://localhost:8101
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 06:39:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 06:39:21 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=500
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you use `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';`
example:

```
constructor(... public http: HTTP){}

var url = 'https://somthing.com';
var data = {'form': form};
var headers = {'Accept' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};

this.http.post(url, data, headers).then((data) => {
  #actions...
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  #actions... 
});
```

Comment: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http`
`npm install --save @ionic-native/http` Install these in your app folder